# Regex, "sum of two regex"

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to make a regex made by 2 regex?

I mean, I have a regex

```
(\bword\b)
```

and

```
(!\\(\w*)(\[.*\])*(\{(\w|\s|\\|\.|\{.\}|`|\-|\:|/|')*\bword\b(\w|\s|\\|\.|\{.\}|`|\-|\:|/|')*\})+)
```

Is there a way to match the first regex plus the second regex? That means, all the "**word**" words that are not inside a "\something{letters letters **word** letters letters}" ?

Comment: Depends on your regex toolkit, but the intersection of two regular languages is a regular language, so the better ones can do this.

Comment: I'm using java. Should I add it to the tags?

Comment: How could anything which matches the second regex *not* match the first? Could you come up with a different example where the intersection is not trivial?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your intention and don't have time to analyze your expressions but `look-ahead` is probably an answer for you

```
(?=\bword\b)(!\\(\w*)(\[.*\])*(\{(\w|\s|\\|\.|\{.\}|`|\-|\:|/|')*\bword\b(\w|\s|\\|\.|\{.\}|`|\-|\:|/|')*\})+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Capturing all `word` outside of `\something{letters letters word letters letters}`:

```
(\bword\b)|(?:\\(?:\w*)(?:\[.*\])*(?:\{(?:\w|\s|\\|\.|\{.\}|`|\-|\:|\/|')*\bword\b(?:\w|\s|\\|\.|\{.\}|`|\-|\:|\/|')*\})+)
```

[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gM1oJ3)

I combined both of your expression using an `OR` and made every capture group in the second a expression a non-capturing group, so you only capture `word` outside of the construct.

Comment: Is the " | " the "or" ? Because when I tried in another regex editor it took both words inside and outside the \something{}

Comment: `|` means `or`, yes. You already used it in an excessive way in your second regex. Note that i replaced every capture group (`()`) in your second expresison with a non-capturing group (`(?:)`). This way you will only capture `word` outside the construct, but still match the whole string I think (there's a difference between matching and capturing).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description: all the **"word"** words that are not inside a "\something{letters letters **word** letters letters}", I think it should be as simple as:

```
\bword\b(?!.*})
```

The solution assumes that the brackets `{}` are balanced.